# Spring boot API's

Tags: java, api, spring-boot

I'm making a challenge that I need to do a credit analysis and use some architectural concepts, which I was in doubt about "API's". It needs to be developed in spring boot which I already did. The conditions of the challenge are:

1. Frontend / Backend.
2. Api concept backend containing swagger documentation of endpoints.
3. API for registration and consultation of proposals.
4. Credit engine API that will review the proposal and make the credit limit decision.

I'm in doubt about steps 3 and 4 where API's are required. What does he mean by that? Do I need to create new Spring boot projects that communicate with each other? What is the best way to dealing with API's?

Thank you!

Comment: It look like typical [client-server architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client–server_model), server need to be developed in Spring Boot. API means typically HTTP based RESTful API. The client (web-app) need to talk to this REST API.

Comment: So I would call my REST backend server directly or I kinda need to develop some interface between my web-app  and backend?
I realised that my concepts about this are bad. I'll improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML form (e.g. registering proposal) will call API with all the form values as key=value pair, your API (Spring Controller) will accept those key=value and process it, apply your business logic, store to database, etc. You can go thru spring boot guides to get more idea, one of such guide for submitting form:

1. https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/
2. https://hellokoding.com/handling-form-submission-example-with-java-spring-boot-and-freemarker/
3. https://medium.com/@grokwich/spring-boot-thymeleaf-html-form-handling-762ef0d51327

Also you can go thru [spring boot pet project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic), a sample showcase app developed with most of spring mvc capabilities.